# Apple Watch Series 4 show full screen wrong

Tags: sprite-kit, watchos, watchos-4

My full screen SpriteKit game which works fine on 38/42mm in Series 2/3, when run on Series 4 (real hardware), seems to cut off the top (approximately the height of the rounded edge) and push down the game scene. This happened regardless of whether it is compiled to watchOS 4 or 5.

What shall I do? I have watch the "Designing for Apple Watch Series 4" talk and have also set to "Fixed to screen edges" in storyboard. "Full Screen" is also switched on.

Comment: This issue is solved in latest Xcode beta.

Answer (score 5):

Still happening for me in Xcode 10.1. Admittedly with a project originally built in Xcode 8 or 9 with the old templates.

I fixed it in:
interface.storyboard --> Interface Controller --> Attributes:

- Full screen = true
- Fixed to screen edges = false

The "fixed to screen edges" is recommended in a number of places, but for my code it was offsetting everything down - INCLUDING THE CLOCK!